# read commaseparated values as one value in python df or dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with products in different colors sets and sizes

```
    artikelnummer   kleur   set maat
0   1   rood    avero   C75
1   1   rood    avero   D80
2   1   rood    avero   E85
3   1   rood    avero   F90
4   2   rood    avero   38
5   2   rood    avero   40
6   2   rood    avero   42
7   2   rood    avero   44
8   1   blauw   avero   C75
9   1   blauw   avero   D80
10  1   blauw   avero   E85
11  1   blauw   avero   F90
12  2   blauw   avero   38
13  2   blauw   avero   40
14  2   blauw   avero   42
15  2   blauw   avero   44
```

I want to make a df with a row for each combination of artikelnummer/kleur/set and in the "maat" column all the sizes of those combinations.

I used

```
df_combimaten=df.groupby(['kleur', 'artikelnummer','set'])['maat'].apply(",".join).reindex()
df_combimaten
```

to group the sizes.

result:

```
kleur  artikelnummer  set  
blauw  1              avero    C75,D80,E85,F90
       2              avero     38, 40, 42, 44
rood   1              avero    C75,D80,E85,F90
       2              avero     38, 40, 42, 44
Name: maat, dtype: object
```

How can I make a normal dataframe form this object?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reset_index` for this:

```
>>> new_df = df_combimaten.reset_index()
>>> print(new_df)
   kleur  artikelnummer    set             maat
0  blauw              1  avero  C75,D80,E85,F90
1  blauw              2  avero      38,40,42,44
2   rood              1  avero  C75,D80,E85,F90
3   rood              2  avero      38,40,42,44
```